# Not why input variable won't switch from NoneType to string

Tags: python, pandas

```
cryptoinput = print(input("Choose cryptocurrency ticker to analyze: "))
   
finalinput = str(cryptoinput)
print(str(finalinput))


#User Input
start = datetime.date(2021, 4, 23)
end = datetime.date(2021, 5, 7)
inputc = pdr.get_data_yahoo(cryptoinput, start, end)
```

Keeps returning that cryptoinput and finalinput are both NoneTypes, how would I go about changing one of these to a string so the pandas function can retrieve the string from the input variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the print when you assign to `cryptoinput`. Also, no need to cast to string, as `input()` returns a string already.

```
cryptoinput = (input("Choose cryptocurrency ticker to analyze: "))
   
finalinput = cryptoinput
print(finalinput)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
cryptoinput = print(input("Choose cryptocurrency ticker to analyze: "))
```

In above code, you're using two functions.
This `input("Choose cryptocurrency ticker to analyze: ")` will print, `"Choose cryptocurrency ticker to analyze: "` and ask for user to input some value.
Suppose user has entered this string:`"some ticker"`.
Now this string "some ticker" will be passed to `print` function and it will printed on screen. Since, `print` is function it will return something, which is `None` in case of `print`. This `None` is assigned to variable `cryptoinput`.

---

You can take `input` as answered by @python_ged.